# Create a document that references another document on Firestore collection

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to create a reference in my collection *Masterclasses* for users who bought that masterclass. So, the workflow in my code:

1. User is registering
2. User is buying that masterclass

Now, I want to add a new document in masterclasses in the new collection called "subscribers" asigned for that user, after purchasing.
The question is, do I have to create the documents with auto generating IDs and add a field userId, then query all the documents and search if my logged in user is equal to that userId, or alternative solution to create the document itself with user id and search by doc id equality?

[image]

Comment: What is the exact query you want to perform? What is the expected result?

Comment: I want to use StreamProvider to retrieve that document when the user is logged in. Both ways should work, but the question is which one is better due to time efficiency, security etc.